# Phenomenon where a repeating pattern on a photo is colorized in alternating stripes

Tags: artifacts, noise

What is the name of the phenomenon where a repeating pattern on a photo is colorized in alternating stripes, like this?

[image]

In addition, does leading software like Photoshop and Lightroom have intelligent tools to combat/remove this phenomenon?

Comment: Photoshop has a specific de-Moiré tool which works well on this. It's referred to in the link-only answer below & I'd rather that user came back & added a précis to their own answer than steal their thunder [& points]. https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTd9g.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is named [moire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern). And happen when the angle of the camera is different by small amount to the pattern.

You can use for example this [manual](https://www.nobledesktop.com/learn/photoshop/removing-moire-patterns) to remove it.

> - From the Photoshop Class folder, open file.
> - Go to View > 100%. He’s been scanned at 359 ppi, and as you can see, a strong dot pattern is evident.
> - First, go to Filter > Noise > Median.
> - Make the radius 2 pixels and click OK.
> - Next, go to Image > Image Size and reduce the image to 150 Pixels/Inch (ppi).
> - Click OK.
> - Finally, go to Filter > Sharpen and apply the Unsharp Mask filter. Try these settings:
>   Amount:   50%
>   Radius:   3 px
>   Threshold:    5
> - Click OK.
>
> Open the original and compare them side-by-side by choosing Window > Arrange > 2-up Vertical. Make sure they are both zoomed to 100%. The final image should have a much more natural texture than the original.

---

Answer (score 2):

This is a [moiré effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern). Not easy to remove, which is why cameras often have a low-pass filter in front of the sensor; this reduces the definition a bit but reduces the moiré. If you have the RAW file, demosaïcing apps can let you use a different demosaïcing algorithm that reduces the occurrence of moiré.

In this very case, just de-saturating the area a bit could be sufficient:
[image]

Comment: While the color moiré was removed, the pattern moiré is still evident.

Answer (score 1):

Bonjour,
this is called Moiré...
Sometimes It is quite tricky to tackle  despite the tools ...
The best tutorial for you : https://photographylife.com/what-is-moire

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.